# Prove $n\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z \cong\Bbb Z/(m/n)\Bbb Z$, where $n\mid m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Just to confirm that this is correct and is a result from first ring isomorphism theorem right?

The map I used is $f: n\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/(m/n\Bbb Z)$ by $f(kn)=k\mod m/n$.

This is apparently surjective, and $\ker{f}=\{kn,k\equiv 0 \pmod{m/n}\}=m\Bbb Z$.

But this seems to be wrong: consider $2\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z=\{2,4,6,8,0\}$. The unity is $6$. But by the induced isomorphism above, $6=2\cdot3$ and $3 \mod 5(=10/2)=3$ instead of $1$ as required. What is wrong here?

Comment: 3 is a generator of Z/5Z, so there's no contradiction here. As far as the group structure is concerned, there's no preferred generator; they're group-theoretically indistinguishable (eg there's an automorphism of Z/5Z sending 1 to 3)

Comment: @Niven Please read the question where the discussion is about the ring. The isomorphism should imply 3 is multiplicative unity.

Comment: Oh in that case, $n\mathbb Z$ isn't a ring with unity, so you shouldn't necessarily expect a map descending from a map out of $n\mathbb Z$ to respect units. You have an isomorphism of rngs, but not an isomorphism of rings with unity.

Comment: @Niven In general the maps $nZ \ni n x \mapsto x \bmod m/n$ and $nZ/mZ\ni nx \bmod m \mapsto x \bmod m/n$ aren't ring homomorphisms, the latter is a group isomorphism if it was a ring homomorphism it would be a ring isomorphism (particular case : with $n=3,m=6$ it is a ring homomorphism because $n^2 =n \bmod m$ and $3Z/6Z\cong Z/2Z$ as rings).

Comment: @reuns What are the conditions under which the ring isomorphism holds?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $2Z/4Z\cong Z/2Z$ where $2Z/4Z:=\{0+4Z,2+4Z\}$. The only nonzero element satisfies $(2+4Z)^2=0+4Z.$ But the only nonzero element of $Z/2Z$ is $1$ and does not have this property. So the claim is false and the proof fail simply because it does not preserve multiplication.

Comment: Are you confusing groups and rings ? $nZ/mZ =n Z/\frac{m}{n} nZ\cong n(Z/\frac{m}{n}Z)$ as groups but not as rings

Comment: @reuns Not at all. Are you?

Comment: @reuns I'm not talking about groups. Please read the question more carefully where I specifically mentioned ring homomorphism.

Comment: Ok but this is the answer to your question : don't confuse groups and rings and the corresponding homomorphisms, the map is a group isomorphism but it is not a ring homomorphism.

Comment: To clarify, this means the statement in the original question is false?