# $n\mathbb{Z} / m \mathbb{Z}$ where $n|m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is there a general structure which is isomorphic to $n\mathbb{Z} / m \mathbb{Z}$ as a group?

I was going through some questions where I had to find to which group $2\mathbb{Z} / 10\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to :

I proceeded as follows :

$2\mathbb{Z} = \{\cdots,-10,-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8,10...\} $

$ 10\mathbb{Z}= \{\cdots,-20,-10,0,10,20 ...\} $

Then  $2\mathbb{Z} / 10\mathbb{Z}$ will have elements of the form $\{\overline{0}, \overline{2},\cdots, \overline{8}   \}$ and will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5$

This I think will hold for $4\mathbb{Z} / 24\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}_6$

I am not sure if my intuition is correct but in general is this true as group isomorphism:

$n\mathbb{Z} / m \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/(m/n) \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: the guess is right. can you find an isomorphism?

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3342454/prove-n-bbb-z-m-bbb-z-cong-bbb-z-m-n-bbb-z-where-n-mid-m).

Answer (score 1):

Let $d := \frac mn \newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$, and consider the composition $h \colon n\Z \to \Z \to \Z/d\Z$ in which the first map is just division by $n$ and the second one is the canonical projection.
As the two maps are surjective homomorphisms, $h$ is a surjective homomorphism.
Now, $\ker h = m\Z$ since
\begin{align*}
x \in \ker h
& \iff \tfrac xn + d\Z = d\Z \\
& \iff \tfrac xn \in d\Z \\
& \iff (\exists k \in \Z) \ \tfrac xn=dk \\
& \iff (\exists k \in \Z) \ x=mk \\
& \iff x \in m\Z.
\end{align*}
Hence, the first isomorphism theorem gives us that $n\Z/m\Z \cong \Z/d\Z$ via the map $x+m\Z \mapsto \tfrac xn + d\Z$.