# Modules: How to find the composition sequence for $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Find the composition sequence of the module $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$. Then to the same for $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

I would have thought that for $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ just taking the prime factors would work:

$$ 0 \le \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \le \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \le \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \le \mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}.$$

I realise that the main thing here is to ensure that $(\mathbb{Z}/p_i\mathbb{Z}) / (\mathbb{Z}/p_{i+1}\mathbb{Z})$ is a simple module, which should be ensured by the fact that $(\mathbb{Z}/p_{i+1}\mathbb{Z},\cdot)$ is cyclic. Therefore for $p_1,\ldots,p_l$ being the distinct prime factors of $n$:

$$ 0 \le \mathbb{Z}/p_1\mathbb{Z} \le \mathbb{Z}/p_2\mathbb{Z} \le \ldots \le \mathbb{Z}/p_l\mathbb{Z} \le \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}.$$

Is this correct?

Comment: How is $\newcommand{\Z}{\Bbb Z} \Z/2\Z$ a submodule of $\Z/3\Z$?

Comment: Because $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} = \{0,1\} \subset \{0,1,2\} = \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: That’s quite wrong, $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is not $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$, but $\{0+n\Bbb Z,1+n\Bbb Z,\dots,(n-1)+n\Bbb Z\}$, where $a+n\Bbb Z = \{a+nk:k\in\Bbb Z\}$. Before doing this exercise you should be familiar with these groups.

Comment: But isnt it the convention to write $1 = [1]$ for the equivalence classes?

Comment: It is, sometimes. But, in this case, the $0$ of $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ is not the same $0$ of $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$. They are different equivalence classes. And, even if we *identify* $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ as a **subset** of $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$, that doesn't mean we can see $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ as a **submodule** of $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$.

Comment: A basic fact of group theory is that the order of a subgroup divides the order of the big group. This directly shows that $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ cannot be a subgroup of $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the correspondence theorem, a subgroup of $\newcommand{\Z}{\Bbb Z} \Z/12\Z$ is of the form $d\Z/12\Z$, where $d\Z$ is an ideal of $\Z$ containing $12\Z$.
Now, the condition $12\Z \subseteq d\Z$ is equivalent to $d \mid 12$, and so $d \in \{1,2,3,4,6,12\}$.
Hence, all the subgroups of $\Z/12\Z$ are
$$
\Z/12\Z,\, 2\Z/12\Z,\, 3\Z/12\Z,\, 4\Z/12\Z,\, 6\Z/12\Z,\, 12\Z/12\Z=0.
$$
Thus, we can consider, for example, the chain of subgroups
$$
0 < 6\Z/12\Z < 3\Z/12\Z < \Z/12\Z.
$$
Using the fact that [$n\Z/m\Z \cong \Z/\frac mn\Z$ if $n \mid m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4547123) and the third isomorphism theorem, we can easily check that the above chain is in fact a composition series.